# Python: Plot a histogram with colored categories

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborn offers the pairplot utility in which the diagonal will provide a histogram with colored categories. See the second example in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html). I am trying to generate a single histogram where the bars are colored by a given category, but so far I have not been able to. Here is what I have tried:

First, I tried to extract the plot, for example:

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue="species")
ax = g.diag_axes[0]
ax.plot()
```

Which does not work, since the `ax` object behaves as emtpy. Alternatively I have not found any direct way of plotting this type of histogram directly. I tried:

```
 g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue="species", vars=['sepal_length'])
```

Which will generate only one histogram, but the y ticks are not correct, and I am not able to change them.

Answer (score 2):

I found that matplotlib offers this functionality directly, as illustrated [here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/statistics/histogram_multihist.html). 
Here is the solution for the iris dataset example:

```
x = [iris.sepal_length[iris.species==sp_name] for sp_name in ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']]
plt.hist(x, 8, density=True, histtype='bar', stacked=True)
```